# Runtime error when sharing code between client/server in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, angular, systemjs

I have a Node.js project with this basic folder structure:

```
├── project
    ├── client
        ├── app
            ├── assets
            │   └── css
            └── components
                ├── about
                ├── categories
                ├── home
                ├── navbar
                └── posts

    ├── common
        ├── model
        └── util
    ├── server
        ├── api
        ├── model (deprecated for ../common/model)
        ├── conf
        └── db
```

`server` is an Express API, `client` is an Angular2 App using this API. I use Gulp to build a `dist` folder which is being deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

**Important:** In `dist`, *Client* lives in `app` folder, while *Server* is in the root.

Everything was working fine until I decided to share some code between *Server* and *Client* (*that's the point in Node.js I thought...*). I've created a `common` folder in project's root with, among others, a post model (`/project/common/model/post.ts`)

In *Server*'s `/project/server/server.ts` I replaced:

```
import {Post} from './model/post'
```

for:

```
import {Post} from '../common/model/post'
```

And it works.

---

But in *Client*'s `/project/client/app/components/posts/post-list.component.ts` I replaced:

```
import {Post} from './post'; // Model was in the same folder here...
```

for:

```
import {Post} from '../../../../common/model/post';
```

and it compiles fine but then, when I try to reach *Client* in my browser, I get:

> zone.js:101 GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/common/model/post 404 (Not Found)
>
> (index):24 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:3000/common/model/post

I've checked and my Gulp's build task is correctly moving the compiled (transpiled) common files to `dist/common`.

Any hint on how to proceed to solve this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably common has to be accessible from the browser, but is your webserver serving up files in the common folder?

In your express configuration you'll likely have something like this to serve up static content:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But did you do the same for the new common folder you have?

Comment: Thank you Colin, your assumption was correct. I've added this line for common folder and now I can retrieve `localhost:3000/common/model/post.js` but my client is asking for `localhost:3000/common/model/post` (no extension) so its still a 404...

Comment: Ok, I found it! I've added the key `'common': { defaultExtension: 'js' }` into my `packages` var in `systemjs.config.js`.